# how is apache usergrid served? free or commercial?

Tags: usergrid

Please guys I want to know if apache usergrid is free or commercial and how large does it scale for example how large can my data be and my users. Thanks

Comment: there are companies that serve user grid instances for a fee. otherwise, user grid being open source, you can host your own instance. if you can find free hosting, then it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Usergrid is free to use and open source.  See the website here:

http://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/

It is backed by Cassandra and can scale to trillions of entities (technically 250 trillion), provided you have the disk storage to support this. In terms of seek times, using big-O notation, it will be:

If you use the UUID, O(1)
If you use the name, it's O(2)
If you search on graph edges it's O(3)

Essentially, storing more entities doesn't change the seek times unless you use complex queries.